# NSDate comparing excludes date with same minute

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have the following if statement

```
if ([date compare:self.appLaunchDate] == NSOrderedDescending || [date compare:self.appLaunchDate] == NSOrderedSame)
```

and the date which filter through are all larger than appLaunchDate.

The thing is there are some dates with the same minute value, but are not making it through the if statement.

How can I get the dates larger than or equal too the appLaunchDate?

e.g. `date to check is: 2012-09-07 12:13:29 +0000 - date of launch is 2012-09-07 12:13:25 +0000`

This should allow the date to check to pass as it is after the launchdate, but for some reason it is not making it through the if statement.

Comment: Well, seconds and milliseconds figure in too.  You'd have to construct your reference NSDate with those fields zeroed.  (And, of course, you have to consider timezone when constructing the date objects.)

Comment: I would like to include them in the comparison. 12:13:29 is after 12:13:25. It should make it through the if check. Not sure why it is not.

Comment: I suspect there's something you're not telling us.  Try using timeIntervalSinceDate (which returns an NSTimeInterval that is typedefed as double) and check it's sign.